# Screen flickering while watching videos full screen

Tags: windows-10, video, graphics-card

It just started recently that everytime I watch any video in full screen, that screen it is on flickers. I have seen, that it happens if any other program causes any popup (like Origins "a friend started playing X game"), but it is not limited to this.

My PC itself is working fine, meaning that powersupply and driver etc. are all okay. I reinstalled windows 2-3 months back (the flickering might have started after this but not sure).

**What could be a cause for this flickering and how can I fix it?**

Note: The flickering is a blackscreen of about 5-10 frames I'd guess and it happens about 3-5 times within like 2 seconds and can occur everywhere in the video. I have the feeling, that the less active I am on the second screen, the less flickering I have. Also if I rewind the video after a flickering, the flickering does most of the time not occur again.

Specs:

- Asus GTX 1070 TI
- Asus ROG STRIX Z270F
- Intel I7-7700K
- 2x Acer Predator XB241H
- 650W power supply

<sub>If you need any more info feel free to ask</sub>

Comment: Seems like the PC can't keep up with CPU/GPU usage. Check Task Manager, Details, to see if some process is using a lot of time, e.g. a browser running a coin-miner.

Comment: `CPU/GPU usage` does not make much sense, as this really only happens during full screen videos. I can run multiple games and the same video (video not in full screen, but games in full screen) without having this flickering at all. But nonetheless I will check

Comment: Have you updated your graphic driver to the latest version?

Comment: After reinstalling windows I certainly loaded the newest version. I had no problem before that reinstall. I can check later again if I still have the newest version